# Attempt to build a generic form component in React without using eval()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm currently trying to code a generic form component for my React applications. I know there are lots of great libraries for that out there, but they all seem like an overkill for me at this point.

My main goal here is to have a `<BasicForm>` component that I can consume, by passing the submit function as `props` and passing input fields and buttons as `children` with the validation requirements along for each field.

My `<BasicForm>` component should handle the form `state`, `onChange`, `onBlur`, `onSubmit`, etc. And should also handle validation (based on each input type that I add as `children`).

The motivation was that I was feeling repetitive everytime a needed to create a new form, by having to manage `state` for inputs, validation, `onChange` and `submit` functions over and over.

Here's the code where I'm consuming the `<Basic Form>`:

**BasicForm-Consumer.js**

```
  <BasicForm
    submitFunction={props.linkEmailAndPassword}
    submitAction={'this.props.submitFunction(this.state.passwordOne)'}
    >
    <PasswordInput
      labelText='Password'
      name='passwordOne'
      placeholder='Enter password...'
      min={6}
      max={12}
      required
    />
    <TextInput
      labelText='Username'
      name='username'
      placeholder='Enter username...'
      initialValue=''
      min={5}
      max={10}
      required
    />
    <button type='submit'>Create Password</button>
  </BasicForm>
```

I'm initially not adding here the source code for the `<BasicForm>` not to make this question too long, but basically it handles all the input `children` with `React.Children.map` and it has validation functions for each kind of input, and also functions to handle change, blur, submit, etc. It also creates a `state` for each input field.

**QUESTION INTRO**

```
  <BasicForm
    submitFunction={props.linkEmailAndPassword}
    submitAction={'this.props.submitFunction(this.state.passwordOne)'}
  >
```

As you can see from the snippet above, in order to send the `submitAction` from the consumer to `<BasicForm>`, I have to wrap it in a string, since it references a `state` that will only exist inside the `<BasicForm>`. And most importantly, the specific `state` part that I need to submit is defined outside of the `<BasicForm>` (in the consumer).

The consumer defines which part or parts of the `state` should be submitted and it will be different on every case, therefore I can't make it as a "generic" `state` name that any `<BasicForm>` would have as a built-in.

So I'm sending as a string and inside `<BasicForm>` I had to use the most NOT RECOMMENDED `eval()` as you can see below:

**BasicForm.js**

```
  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.validateAllFields();
    eval(this.props.submitAction);
  }
```

**PROPER QUESTION**

How bad is the `eval()` in this case? Am I exposing my app to "malicious hackers" by doing this? Should I sanitize it in any way, even though it's not a user input? Is there another way around this? I'm really happy by not having to build a form from scratch everytime I need one. Now I just focus on the fields and the validation requirements. Thanks for your time!

**EXTRA INFO**

P.S.: Here's the code for one of the input components `TextInput`. The `PasswordInput` is very much just like this. The only difference is `type='password'`:

**TextInput.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Label from './Common/Label';

const TextInput = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Label
        name={props.name}
        labelText={props.labelText}
      >
      </Label>
      <div>
      <input
        type='text'
        id={props.name}
        name={props.name}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        onBlur={props.onBlur}
      >
      </input>
      </div>
      {props.isInvalidMsg && <div><span>{props.isInvalidMsg}</span></div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

Comment: For the TextInput, why don't you use a prop named ```props.type``` to change the type. So you wouldn't need an extra PasswordInput or NumberInput.

Comment: @Gh05d I've thought of that. But since I'll probably validate a password, a text and a number in very different ways, I've decided to create a component for each type (I use the component name to distinguish them). Also the code becomes more explicit when you consume a `<TextInput>` and `<NumberInput>` rather than two `<BasicInput>` with the prop type=text and number. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eval is almost never welcome because it imposes security risks, performance penalties and indicates that there are design issues.

It depends on its usage if there are security risks. If there's a chance that evaluated expression may contain user input, directly or indirectly, there's security risk. Otherwise only performance and design concerns apply.

In this case this means that `BasicForm` failed to provide reasonable API to parent components, so it ended up with `eval`. A proper way to do this is a callback.

Since parent component shouldn't be generally aware of `BasicForm` implementation details and access its instance, `BasicForm` `this` shouldn't be available in a callback. `BasicForm` props are already available in a callback - they are passed in parent component. Since it's known `BasicForm` `state` contains values from its child inputs, it should be available in a callback.

So `BasicForm` callback may look like:

```
  <BasicForm
    onSubmit={state => props.linkEmailAndPassword(state.passwordOne)}}

  ...

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.validateAllFields();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  }
```

In case there's a need for `onSubmit` callback to access any `BasicForm` data besides its state, this means that this data should be passed as callback argument, too.